# Getting Printer Status from a Cocoa App

Tags: cocoa

How can I get status on a printer from a Cocoa app.

I would like to get the number of queued jobs and the current status of the printer (running, paused, error, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Just use the cups api to get job details for a printer.

int nJobs = cupsGetJobs2(http_, &jobs ,NULL, 0, CUPS_WHICHJOBS_ACTIVE);